# auto generate data access layer in PHP

Tags: php

is there any framework or tool that auto generate ORM (Object-Relational Mapping) layer for PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Check these out:**

http://www.doctrine-project.org/

http://xyster.devweblog.org/

http://flourishlib.com/docs/ObjectRelationalMapping

http://propel.phpdb.org/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Fat-Free Framework's [Axon ORM](http://fatfree.sourceforge.net#axon) has no unnecessary code generator. It auto-maps the schema on the fly.